# Encoding Huffman file with bool and std::bitset

Tags: c++, stl, boolean, huffman-code, bitset

I need to encode bytes of a file via Huffman method and write the encoded bits to another "compressed" file. What should I use for storing the encoded bits, `std::vector<bool>` or `std::vector<std::bitset<1>>`? I have been suggested to use `std::bitset<8>` all by itself, but since they are Huffman encoded bits, their length varies with byte frequency. And `std::bitset` should has constant length, which means longer encoded values will lose its most significant bits and shorter encoded values with have extra zeros padded into them, thereby changing the values. Is there any way to overcome this? I have been told `std::vector<bool>` is not very preferable because it is not a C-style array. Can I use `std::vector<std::bitset<1>>` instead? Are there any disadvantages to it? Please tell me.

**NOTE: This is a school assignment, so I'm not supposed to use anything other than C++ and STL. So, please don't suggest Boost libraries or the like, because I can't use them.**

On another very important side note, I tried using `std::vector<bool>`, but I am not getting desired output.

```
int main()
{
    std::string Input_File_Name, Encoded_Output_File_Name, Decoded_Output_File_Name;

    Input_File_Name = "C:\\Users\\WDR\\Pictures\\grrm.jpg";

    Encoded_Output_File_Name = Input_File_Name + ".encoded";

    Decoded_Output_File_Name = Input_File_Name + ".decoded";



    File_Handler File;

    std::vector<std::uint8_t> File_Data = File.Read_Input_File(Input_File_Name);

    std::map<std::uint8_t, int> File_Byte_Frequency = File.Generate_Byte_Frequency(Input_File_Name);



    Binary_Tree Huffman_Tree(File_Byte_Frequency.begin(), File_Byte_Frequency.end());

    std::vector<bool> Encoded_Bytes = Huffman_Tree.Encode(File_Data.begin(), File_Data.end());

    File.Write_Encoded_File(Encoded_Bytes, Encoded_Output_File_Name);



    std::vector<std::uint8_t> Decoded_File_Data;

    Huffman_Tree.Decode(Encoded_Bytes, std::back_inserter(Decoded_File_Data));

    File.Write_Decoded_File(Decoded_File_Data, Decoded_Output_File_Name);

    return 0;
}
```

The `Read_Input_File()` function reads a file in Binary and stores it in a `std::vector<std::uint8_t>`. Then, the `Generate_Byte_Frequency()` creates a `std::map` of the byte and its frequency. I am not posting that code here because it works perfectly. I printed it out to check and it works for small and large files as well(`long` for large files, but `int` works for now). The Binary_Tree class constructor `Huffman_Tree()` also works perfectly. It builds a Huffman_Tree using a `std::priority_queue` and puts them into a `std::map<std::uint8_t, std::vector<bool>>` where each byte and its corresponding encoded value is stored.

The problem might be in the `Encode()` method or the `Write_Encoded_File()` method. After encoding the file and writing the encoded values to another file, I am getting a 751KB output file for a 94KB input file. I don't think the problem is in the `Encode()` method, because it works for encoding character strings. So, it has to be the writing method. Nevertheless, I'm posting both methods here.

```
std::vector<bool> Binary_Tree::Encode(std::vector<std::uint8_t>::iterator First_Element, std::vector<std::uint8_t>::iterator Last_Element)
{
    std::vector<bool> Byte_Encoding;

    while(First_Element != Last_Element)
    {
        std::map<std::uint8_t, std::vector<bool>>::iterator Current_Element = Encoded_Values.find(*First_Element);

        Byte_Encoding.insert(Byte_Encoding.end(), Current_Element->second.begin(), Current_Element->second.end());

        ++First_Element;
    }

    return Byte_Encoding;
}

void File_Handler::Write_Encoded_File(std::vector<bool> &Encoded_Data, const std::string &Output_File_Name)
{
    std::ofstream Output_File(Output_File_Name, std::ios::binary);

    if(!Output_File)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Unable to write to file: " + Output_File_Name);
    }

    std::copy(Encoded_Data.begin(), Encoded_Data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<bool>(Output_File, ""));
}
```

Finally, the `Decode()` and `Write_Decoded_File()` methods in the main function work perfectly giving me the exact same input file. And furthermore, since the return value of the `Encode()` method is given as an argument to the `Decode()` method, this is further evidence that the `Encode()` method is working properly. In that case, it means that I am writing it into the encoded file wrongly. Please help me in correcting it. Also, please tell me about the `bool vs. bitset` preference. Thank you. Apologies for the long question.

Comment: looks like someone got this homework before you reading-and-writing-bit-by-bit-in-c-for-huffman-encoding.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442093/reading-and-writing-bit-by-bit-in-c-for-huffman-encoding?rq=1

Comment: @AnthonyLambert That didn't come up when I searched the site. And I always search before I post, because who wants to be told off for creating a duplicate? However, it's not a duplicate. The OP has a problem decompressing. I don't have that problem. My problem is about not writing encoded bits properly into the file. And also, I asked about bool and bitset preference.

Comment: just flagged it because they were solving the same problem in the same language... I didn't tell you off now did I ?! +1 for encouragement and to cheer you up!

Comment: @AnthonyLambert No, I didn't mean **you** were telling me off. I was just defending myself from people who would usually jump at the opportunity if they thought that OP was being ignorant about the problem. You're fine, though. And thanks for the encouragement. **:-)** Do you know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: well I personally would use an unsigned char (byte) and shift the bits into it. byte = (byte << 1) | (bit); and write it out to file every 8 shifts.

Comment: @AnthonyLambert OK... Thank you for telling me that. I have a couple of questions, though. Do I need to change my `Write_Encoded_File()` method? Is it correct? And also, what does `bit` refer to in your solution? How is it related to the `std::vector<bool>`? Please tell me this, thank you.